# Error in ajax request on web server using Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm having ajax error in my site but it runs smoothly on localhost. I've already checked the console but there's no error indicated. Here's my site [glacierpayroll.com](http://glacierpayroll.com) **Id: 2 pass: 2 Level: HR supervisor**

view - ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('/userprofile/basicinfo_list')?>",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {


        $('[name="user_id"]').val(data.user_id);
        $('[name="firstname"]').val(data.firstname);
        $('[name="middlename"]').val(data.middlename);
        $('[name="lastname"]').val(data.lastname);
        $('[name="department"]').val(data.department);
        $('[name="address"]').val(data.address);
        $('[name="position"]').val(data.position);
        $('[name="contact_no"]').val(data.contact_no);



    },

});
```

controller

```
public function basicinfo_list()
{
    $data = $this->profile->emp_get_by_id($this->session- >userdata('username'));
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

model

```
 public function emp_get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->emp_table);
    $this->db->where('user_id =', $id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: Is that code in a javascript file or part of a view?  Is the issue with the AJAX call, the server side code or with something which is being returned?

Comment: The information you have provided is not enough. What triggers the ajax, onclick function? provide the Html and javascript files so that we can help you

Comment: @gabe3886 This code is part of the view and I think the issue is in server side because in my localhost it's doesn't have any errors. Have you checked my site? You can see there that the datatables are not able to retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

Turn $config['csrf_prote‌​ction'] = FALSE; and open the ajax called controller in your browser, if you get an Internal server error 500 something wrong with the code, but if you can't get an error the problem in the ajax call. Or try to contact with the hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've already set it to false and when I tried to call the controller on my browser, I got the json string returned by the function. So meaning to say the problem is with the hosting? Because I just deployed it on a subdomain so I'm not sure if there's restrictions in some stuffs.